# Characters are not escaped in written XML-file (java)

Tags: java, xml, escaping

I'm using **org.w3c.dom** for manipulation of a XML file. 
I load a xml, change the value of an attribute and write it back to the disk. However, all the apostrophes are in the xml as ', not as `&apos;`
How can I escape them in the XML file?

I load the file the following way:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(path/to/file.xml);
```

I change the attribute by calling

```
attr.setNodeValue(newAttrValue)
```

I also tried `attr.setNodeValue(org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML(newAttrValue))`

I write the XML the following way:

```
try {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(path/to/file.xml));

    transformer.transform(source, result);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If the attribute value is quoted with double-quotes (`"`), the apostrophes don’t need to be escaped.

Comment: so I would need to replace ' with `&apos;` manually?

Comment: Why do you care? You're producing valid XML, so any XML parser should be able to parse it. And it's shorter and more readable, too.